# how to query the occuring time of the max wind from a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I want to find the occuring time of the max wind, the max wind, and total rain from a database. The database have three columns: observerTime, wind and rain, how to generate the SQL statement to get the result ?

Comment: Narrow question.You can have two different occurring time for the same wind value which is the maximum.

Comment: I am using MS SQL SERVER 2005, but I only have a account which does't have the administration previlege.

Comment: So not clear what total rain means

Answer (score 0):

```
select observerTime from t where wind = (select max(wind) from t)
```

or if you need the last date when it occures

```
select max(observerTime) from t where wind = (select max(wind) from t)
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't describe the situation clearly, the time of the max wind is only a part of the wanted result. I have updated the question. Anyway thank you for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the database, but one of the following is likely to work:

```
select top 1 *, (select sum(rain) from t) as TotalRain
order by wind desc
```

or:

```
select *, (select sum(rain) from t) as TotalRain
from t
order by wind desc
limit 1
```

or

```
select *, (select sum(rain) from t) as TotalRain
from (select *
      from t
      order by wind desc
     ) t
where rownum = 1
```

Comment: I would really like to add "from t" to the first query, but Stackoverflow won't let me.

Comment: I also want to get the total rain which need to use the sum() function.

Comment: @yorua007 . . . I answered the question before you modified it.  I'm having a hard time uploading answers, so someone else may have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
select t1.observerTime, 
  t1.wind, 
  (select sum(rain) from yourtable) TotalRain
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select max(wind) MaxWind
  from yourtable
) t2
  on t1.wind = t2.maxwind
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e60a2/6)

Since you are using SQL Server, you can also use `row_number()`:

```
select observertime,
  wind,
  (select sum(rain) from yourtable) TotalRain
from
(
  select observertime,
    wind,
    rain,
    row_number() over(order by wind desc) rn
  from yourtable
) src
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e60a2/12)